# Proof of an inequality connected to Diophantine approximation

Tags: inequality, diophantine-approximation, fractional-part

I'm recently doing some work that's vaguely connected with Dirichlet's approximation theorem. I came across this inequality that I haven't been able to prove.

$$\forall\ a, b \in \mathbb{Z^+}, N\geq1,\ N<b<aN$$

Prove that

$$ \left( \frac{a}{b}\left\lceil \frac{b}{a} \right\rceil  \right) < \frac{1}{N}$$

Where $\lceil x \rceil$ denotes the ceiling function of $x$, and $\left( x  \right)$ denotes the fractional part of $x$.

I verified the inequality using a computer for small values of $a$, $b$, $N$ and it seems to work, but I can't figure out how to prove it.

Comment: Just checking, $N$ real?

Comment: @Shuri2060 Yes, $N$ is real.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Who uses **parentheses** to represent fractional part...)

False.  Counterexample:  \begin{align*}
a &= 1117,  \\
b &= 133,  \text{ and }  \\
N &= 294/5 = 58.8  \text{.}
\end{align*}

We observe $a,b \in \Bbb{Z}^+$, $N \geq 1$, and
$$  N = 58.8 < b = 133 < a N = 65679.6  \text{.}  $$

Then \begin{align*}
\left\{ \frac{a}{b} \left\lceil \frac{b}{a} \right\rceil \right \}
    &= \left\{ \frac{1117}{133} \left\lceil \frac{133}{1117} \right\rceil \right \}  \\
    &= \left\{ \frac{1117}{133} \cdot 1 \right \}  \\
    &= \left\{ 8.39849{\dots} \right\}  \\
    &= 0.39849{\dots} \\
    &\not\lt \frac{1}{N}  \\
    &= \frac{5}{294}  \\
    &= 0.01700{\dots} \text{.}
\end{align*}

Comment: @Shuri2060 : You write $\frac{a}{b} < \frac{1}{N}$, but this is not the case in this counterexample.